# forge viewer get element dbId for multiple models same time NOP_VIEWER.getSelection(); []

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to retrieve dbId from multibale model from a viewer, I am using `getSelection` method
also the `getSelection` it work with NOP_VIEWER i am wondering if there something like `NOP_VIEWER.getAllModels()[needed model].getSelection()`
the result is only from one model, I am wondering if there is a way to get the dbid from all models at the same time

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with multiple models, you'll want to use the "aggregate" versions of methods, for example, [getAggregateSelection](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getaggregateselection-callback). For more details on this, please refer to https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher.